# How to set a dynamic list of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have the following HTML code relating to a checkbox group in Oracle APEX:

```
<fieldset class="checkbox_group" id="P300_CELL_TECH" tabindex="-1" disabled="disabled">
    <legend class="hideMeButHearMe">
        <div id="cell-filter">
            <div style="font-size:10px;margin-left:-11px;">Select All</div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="select-all-cell" id="select-all-cell" disabled="disabled"/>
            <div class="cb-filter-label">Cells</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </legend>
    <table class="checkbox_group" role="presentation" summary="">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_0">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_0">0</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_1">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_1">1</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_2">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_2">2</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_3">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_3">3</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_4">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_4">4</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="p_v42" id="P300_CELL_TECH_5">
                    <label for="P300_CELL_TECH_5">5</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Using jQuery, how can I iterate through all these input checkbox types and set all these checkboxes to checked, without using the `name="p_v42"` (as the name can change) and not knowing the exact number of checkboxes within this fieldset as it may vary?

I am seeking an answer that just concentrates on each `<input type="checkbox" ...>`.

I also have other checkboxes on the same page but to not want to target those, just the ones described above.

The top level id will always be:

```
id="P300_CELL_TECH"
```

Comment: A quick search on Google: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
jQuery(":checkbox[id^='P300_CELL_TECH']").prop('checked', true)
```

Or

```
jQuery(".checkbox_group :checkbox[id^='P300_CELL_TECH']" ).prop('checked', true)
```

Or simply

```
jQuery('.checkbox_group :checkbox" ).prop('checked', true)
```

Comment: *"Because `:checkbox` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:checkbox` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="checkbox"]` instead."* -- http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: @Blazemonger agree :)

Comment: @Aamir - tried to accept it before but didn't allow as I had to wait for 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.checkbox_group input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```